# Nativescript doesn't recognize Xcode (High Sierra)

Tags: xcode, nativescript, macos-high-sierra

I'm on High Sierra with Xcode Version 9.0.1 (9A1004).
When running `tns doctor` I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Xcode is not installed or is not configured properly.
You will not be able to build your projects for iOS or run them in the iOS Simulator.
To be able to build for iOS and run apps in the native emulator, verify that you have installed Xcode.
```

If I run the installation script, furthermore I get:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
Xcode is not installed or not configured properly. Download, install, set it up and run this script again.
```

As you might have guessed, I have Xcode installed from the app store and I've also installed cocoapods and xcodeproj. This is the only warning that I get.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

I found this answer here:

http://overengineer.net/fixing-nativescript-s-xcode-is-not-installed-or-is-not-configured-properly-on-macos

Comment: Thank you, DuckDuckGo, for getting me to this answer.

Comment: Worked on Mojave too.

Comment: Super. worked on Nativescript

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today, but running the recommended command didn't help. I found that running the command

`$ tns doctor`

walked me through a series of prompts and corrected the issue. I did have to restart my terminal after the program completed in order for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Open Xcode than go to Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools after that it'll automatically take a path for the same. The system may ask for sudo password.